# Fill the null Value

Tags: sql, select

I want a select query that fills the null values in column 2 [Tags.1] with the distinct value from column 1 [ResourcesUD]

```
The given table:
ReourceID    [Tags.1]
1x           ws             
2x           NULL
1x           ws
3x           qs
2x           sg
4x           ee
3x           NULL
4x           NULL
2x           sg
```

The expected result:

```
ReourceID    [Tags.1]
1x           ws             
2x           sg
1x           ws
3x           qs
2x           sg
4x           ee
3x           qs
4x           ee
2x           sg
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste your data as formatted text instead.

Comment: As to the problem: What is this you are showing us? A database table? Then it probably shouldn't contain the tags column anyway, because if you expect it to contain the same tag for the same resourceid, then the table is not normalized. Or is this a query result? If so, show us the query. You should be able to avoid the nulls then in the first place.

Comment: "Query that **fills** ..." - does it mean that you're looking for UPDATE? What is desired result? Which database do you use? Not all of them share the same syntax.

Comment: This is a dumb table, simply what is required is, a select statement that results in replacing null values in column2 with the equivalent value from column1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 SELECT  ResourceID, isnull(Tags.1, select top 1 b.ResourceID from
 table b where b.ResourceID=a.ResourceID) FROM table a
```

Comment: Hi Masoud, Thanks it works with me.

Comment: SELECT  ResourceID, isnull([Tags.1], (select top 1 b.[Tags.1] from
mytable b where b.ResourceID=a.ResourceID)) as [Tags.1] FROM mytable a

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the question correctly. If you want a select query that filters the null values in column 2, here is the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ResourceID, Tags.1 FROM table WHERE Tags.1 IS NULL
```

Not sure, what database you are using and the Tags.1 is a valid table name. Better if you can change it to Tags_1

Comment: Hi iynga, thanks for your reply. my concern is that column1 has distinct values, I want to fill the null values in column2 with the equivalent values from column1. For example column2 in the second row should be "sg".